# Ubuntu apt-get upgrade error on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apache2, php, dependencies

I am trying to use command `sudo apt-get upgrade` command on mu ubuntu 12.04. But is is showing me the error .**This is after i upgraded my php 5.4 to php5.5**.

> You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
>       The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>        libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: apache2-api-20120211
>                              Depends: apache2 (>= 2.4)
>       E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

then i ran the command

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

to fix the dependency issue and it is also giving me the error

```
 Unpacking apache2-bin (from
 .../apache2-bin_2.4.16-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1_amd64.deb) ... dpkg:
 error processing
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.16-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1_amd64.deb
 (--unpack):  trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man8/apache2.8.gz',
 which is also in package apache2.2-common 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10 dpkg-deb
 (subprocess): subprocess data was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
 dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
 Unpacking apache2-data (from
 .../apache2-data_2.4.16-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1_all.deb) ... dpkg:
 error processing
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-data_2.4.16-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1_all.deb
 (--unpack):  trying to overwrite '/usr/share/apache2/icons/a.png',
 which is also in package apache2.2-common 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10 dpkg-deb
 (subprocess): subprocess data was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
 dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
 Preparing to replace apache2 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10 (using
 .../apache2_2.4.16-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1_amd64.deb) ... Unpacking
 replacement apache2 ... dpkg: error processing
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2_2.4.16-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1_amd64.deb
 (--unpack):  trying to overwrite
 '/usr/share/apache2/ask-for-passphrase', which is also in package
 apache2.2-common 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10 dpkg-deb (subprocess): subprocess
 data was killed by signal (Broken pipe) dpkg-deb: error: subprocess
 <decompress> returned error exit status 2 Processing triggers for
 man-db ... Errors were encountered while processing: 
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.16-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-data_2.4.16-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2_2.4.16-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1_amd64.deb
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: But the command should be `apt-get -f install` @ShowStopper

Comment: will it make any diffrence??

Comment: add the output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem.
Got it working by running the following:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.16-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-data_2.4.16-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2_2.4.16-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1_amd64.deb
```

After that sudo "apt-get -f install" worked fine!

Comment: pretty good hint

Answer (score 1):

Add repository with

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
apt-get update
```

Remove all previous php versions. Then install freshly a version of your preference. Then add modules php-cgi for cgi and fcgi.

Now you would be able to use FCGI and cgi scripts. `mod_apache` will be a problem but you would be able to use this. Make sure to restart apache after installing php-cgi